# Multiprocessing never executing function keeps repeating code before function

Tags: python, multiprocessing, threadpool

I have a multiprocessing pool , that runs with 1 thread, and it keeps repeating the code before my function, i have tried with different threads, and also, i make things like this quite a bit, so i think i know what is causing the problem but i dont understand why, usually i use argparse to to parse files from the user, but i instead wanted to use input, no errors are thrown so i honestly have no clue.

```
from colorama import Fore
import colorama
import os
import ctypes
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
import random



colorama.init(autoreset=False) 
print("headerhere")
#as you can see i used input instead of argparse
g = open(input(Fore.RED + " File Path?: " + Fore.RESET))
gg = open(input(Fore.RED + "File Path?: " + Fore.RESET))
#I messed around with this to see if it was the problem, ultimately disabling it until i fixed it, i just use 1 thread 
threads = int(input(Fore.RED + "Amount of Threads?: " + Fore.RESET))

arrange = [lines.replace("\n", "")for lines in g]
good = [items.replace("\n", "") for items in gg]
#this is all of the code before the function that Pool calls

def che(line):
    print("f")

    #i would show my code but as i said this isnt the problem since ive made programs like this before, the only thing i changed is how i take file inputs from the user
def main():
    pool = Pool(1)
    pool.daemon = True
    result = pool.map(che, arrange)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()






if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: yes fixed it sorry, and yes all the code before the function che is being repeated, even the inputs

Comment: it cant be che, its not even running, as i put a test print statement inside and it didnt even print anything, but all im doing is making get/post requests

Comment: i just changed the code inside to print("f"), same results

Comment: through commmand prompt, first i tried compiling with an exe using pyinstaller becuase i thought there wouldnt be problems, but then there was so i just opened cmd and typed "python pathtofile"

Comment: Any idea @Carcigenicate

Comment: You are not using thread pool but process pool. All top level code will be executed again in a child process.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

print('header')

def func(n):
    print(f'func {n}')

def main():
    pool = Pool(3)
    pool.map(func,[1,2,3])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

On OSes where "spawn" (Windows and MacOS) or "forkserver" (some Unix) are the [default start methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#contexts-and-start-methods), the sub-process imports your script.  Since `print('header')` is at global scope, it will run the first time a script is imported into a process, so the output is:

```
header
header
header
header
func 1
func 2
func 3
```

A multiprocessing script should have everything meant to run once inside function(s), and they should be called once by the main script via `if_name__ == '__main__':`, so the solution is to move it into your `def main():`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func(n):
    print(f'func {n}')

def main():
    print('header')
    pool = Pool(3)
    pool.map(func,[1,2,3])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
header
func 1
func 2
func 3
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the top level code before the definition of `che` to only be executed in the master process, then place it in a function and call that function in `main`.

In multiprocessing, the top level statements will be interpreted/executed by both the master process and every child process.  So, if some code should be executed only by the master and not by the children, then such code should not placed that at the top-level.  Instead, such code should be placed in functions and these functions should be invoked in the main scope, i.e., in the scope of `if` block controlled by `__main__` (or called in the `main` function in your code snippet).